# Handling connection failures in apache-camel

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka

I am writing an apache-camel RabbitMQ consumer. I would like to react somehow to connection problems (i.e. try to reconnect). Is it possible to configure apache-camel to automatically reconnect?

If not, how can I find out that a connection to the queue was interrupted? I've done the following test:

- start the queue (and some producer)
- start my consumer (it was getting messages as expected)
- stop the queue (the messages stopped arriving, as expected, but no exception was thrown)
- start the queue (no new messages were received)

I am using camel in Scala (via akka-camel), but a Java solution would be probably also OK

Comment: If you are using Akka then this sounds like the perfect case for supervision.  Have a separate supervisor for your camel consumer endpoint actor that get the connection failure exception from the consumer actor and then decides whether or not to send a message back to the child to restart it or not.  That way you separate the consumption of data from the semantic of connection management

Comment: But I am not getting an exception within the consumer actor, thus I don't know how to detect that an endpoint is not working

Comment: Are you sure that your consumer actor is not receiving other messages (like failures) that you just might not be handling in the `receive` PF?  You can add a `case any => println(any)` and then see if that gets hit when the connection failure occurs.

Comment: I have the Any case, nothing is catched

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in the flag `automaticRecoveryEnabled=true` to the URI, Camel will reconnect if the connection is lost.

Answer (score 1):

For automatic RabbitMQ resource recovery (Connections/Channels/Consumers/Queues/Exchanages/Bindings) when failures occur, check out [Lyra](https://github.com/jhalterman/lyra) (which I authored). Example usage:

```
Config config = new Config()
  .withRecoveryPolicy(new RecoveryPolicy()
    .withMaxAttempts(20)
    .withInterval(Duration.seconds(1))
    .withMaxDuration(Duration.minutes(5)));
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions().withHost("localhost");
Connection connection = Connections.create(options, config);
```

The rest of the API is just the [amqp-client](http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html) API, except your resources are automatically recovered when failures occur.

I'm not sure about camel-rabbitmq specifically, but hopefully there's a way you can swap in your own resource creation via Lyra.

Answer (score 0):

Current camel-rabbitmq just create a connection and the channel when the consumer or producer is started. So it don't have a chance to catch the connection exception :(.